# Google Cloud Storage auto delete folder contents

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a temporary folder being generated in my storage bucket in GCS which is used to upload files into. Upon upload, if the file checks certain parameters, it is transferred to another folder. However, if it fails the checks, the file remains in the temporary folder. Is there any way to make GCS automatically purge / delete all files within the temporary folder independent of my app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object Lifecycle to specify your path and the duration (I mean the time to live of the object)

More details here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle

---

**Edit 1**

In the step 1, select delete object action. Then, in the step 2 select a prefix match

[image]

Remember that folder does not exist in Cloud Storage, the object name is always the fully qualified path, prefix ("folder" like) and the leaf name.

Comment: How can I do this for only 1 folder in the bucket and not the entire bucket?